# How to remove redundant values in a dictionary with python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a large dictionary with times value of each day. The problem is the time value is duplicated. They must be 7 list of times but there are 14 of them. How to remove items with indexes of 8 - 14 in the values of the dictionary? I don't have any solution so I have not tried it.

```
mydict = {'x': [(['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'])],
 'y': [(['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'])]}

myresult = {'x': [(['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'])],
     'y': [(['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'])]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another way to do it with a for loop.

```py
myresult = {}
for key in mydict:
    myresult[key] = [mydict[key][0][:7]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple dict comprehension works:

```
{k: [v[0][:7]] for k, v in mydict.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to @Asocia's answer, Which works best if the location of the duplicate value is know, the below option can be used if the location of duplicate values is random.

```
{k: list(set(mydict[k][0][0])) for k in mydict.keys()}
```

Comment: Note: The indices to the key `mydict[k][0][0]` is based on the value object in the question. I am still not sure on why it is a `list of tuple of lists` where both outer list and tuple contains only one value ( may be because it is a sample value or may be a typo).

Answer (score -1):

You can get your result by `slicing` the inner array.

```
mydict = {'x': [(['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'])],
 'y': [(['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'], ['08:00  - 18:00 PM'])]}

myresult = {}

for key in mydict:
    myresult[key] = [mydict[key][0][:7]]

print(myresult)
```